# How to create multiple borders on an img?

Tags: html, css

I want to add multiple borders on a single image. Is this possible through CSS?

Example: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/31/multiplebg.jpg/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment it's not possible to make more than one border in CSS. You can kind of fake having three borders by [using some clever css3 shadowing techniques](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/RkQ9h/1/).

```
div
{
    margin: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #f00;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 2px 2px #0f0, 0px 0px 2px 5px #00f;
}
```

But I'd just go with adding the borders to the image as this isn't supported by IE. (Maybe IE9 supports it.)

Answer (score 1):

Nest your `<img>`  inside multiple container and apply border to each

```
<div id="b1">

    <div id="b2">

        <div id="b3">
            <img src="" />
        </div> 

    </div> 

</div>
```

Then apply border to each like

```
#b1 { border: 1px #000 solid; }
#b2 { border: 1px #f00 solid; }
#b3 { border: 1px #0f0 solid; }
img { border: 1px #00f solid; }
```

### Or

Use a image that has multiple border on it and using `border-image` property

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks, what is not semantic about it? What would you do, if you need multiple border?

Comment: sorry my fri but i don't used any div only single img tag

Comment: @Rohitazad, AFAIK, I don't think you have that many options, its either this or images as i mentioned.

Comment: I'm sorry but when it comes to adding three unneeded divs just to create some visual effect, I don't believe that's the way to go. Good suggestion about the border image property though, I had forgotten about that :)

Answer (score 0):

Easy, using CSS3 this is a very simple problem to solve.

If using 'outline' fits your particular situation don't be afraid to use it.

http://tinkerbin.com/tCGF0mfW

Answer (score 0):

yes possible mite....

See Here

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">

#full-border5 {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FF9600;
    border: 5px solid #FF0000;
    padding: 40px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}
#full-border5:before {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #4AA929;
    border: 5px solid #FFEA00;
    bottom: 5px;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    left: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    top: 5px;
    z-index: -1;
}
#full-border5:after {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    border: 5px solid #F000FF;
    bottom: 25px;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    left: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 25px;
    top: 25px;
    z-index: -1;
}
#full-border5 p:first-child {
    margin-top: 0;
}
#full-border5 p:first-child:before {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #7200FF;
    border: 5px solid #00B4FF;
    bottom: 15px;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    left: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
    top: 15px;
    z-index: -1;
}


</style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="full-border5">
           <img src="slider_img8.jpg" width="145" height="214" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Shadow is not yet cross-browser friendly.

The simplest (and cross-browser friendly) way is to use a combination of padding and border.

Example:

```
<img src="<path>" class="doubleBorder" />
```

And the CSS:

```
.doubleBorder {
padding: 10px; background: orange;
border: 5px solid green;
}
```

Hope this helps.